# iPhone iPad Bluetooth Transfer

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, transfer

Is it possible to programatically transffer the data between iPhone and iPad using bluettoth?
I'm able to transfer the data between iPhone and iPhone but not between iPhone and iPad.
I have used the same seeion id on both iPhone and iPad. The app is not universal binary.
I have created two sepearte apps. DOes this make any difference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Same code should work on both. My app does exactly that.

Comment: Did you use the same bundle identifier for the iPad as well as the iPhone App?